# How does one view the "inline docs" of a .cpp file?

Tags: documentation, comments

I have cpp files peppered with comments such as the following before every function:

```
/**
 *  @brief Set the normal and expansion handshake timeouts.
 *
 *  @param wm               Array of wiimote_t structures.
 *  @param wiimotes         Number of objects in the wm array.
 *  @param normal_timeout   The timeout in milliseconds for a normal read.
 *  @param exp_timeout      The timeout in millisecondsd to wait for an expansion handshake.
 */
```

I assume from the format that there has to be some way of exporting this into a "friendly" format, perhaps html, which can then be read in a manner similar to the Java API. How would I do this?

(I'm on Windows 7, running MS Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific document comment style you quote is almost certainly intended for processing by [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/). It can generate decent quality documentation in several output formats from comments in sources of many C-like languages. There are also plugins available to process comments in some non-C languages for inclusion in the same document.

If you have the AT&T [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) tools installed and configure Doxygen to use them, then it can also draw a number of useful diagrams from the source code for inclusion in the documentation.

If the project is using Doxygen, then there is almost certainly a configuration file that specifies what source files to include, what formats to generate, and options related to the detailed processing. It would likely be named `doxyfile`, or something similar.

A common output format is the HTML for a complete web site. One example available online is the website for Doxygen itself, which is almost entirely generated by running Doxygen in its source tree.

Comment: I highly recommend Doxygen for projects written in C-like languages. The discipline of writing "good enough" comments is often useful, and provides a clear statement of the "contract" each function is offering to fulfill.